# Precisamos da tag Google?

Tags: debate

Hoje percebi a existência da [google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google):

> Use esta tag para coisas relacionadas ao buscador da empresa. Se for para outros produtos existem tags específicas, não a use separado. Por exemplo evite usar esta tag e "maps", prefira "google-maps".

E notei que ela é quase sempre utilizada de forma errada.

- [Por que essa fórmula está incorreta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368668/por-que-essa-f%c3%b3rmula-est%c3%a1-incorreta)

  - Pergunta sobre Google Planilha, não sobre o buscador;
- [Como filtrar de forma que acentos não sejam diferenciados no Google Sheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367926/como-filtrar-de-forma-que-acentos-n%c3%a3o-sejam-diferenciados-no-google-sheets)

  - Pergunta sobre Google Sheets, não sobre o buscador;
- [Push no Datalayer dinamicamente após Ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367623/push-no-datalayer-dinamicamente-ap%C3%B3s-ajax)

  - Pegunta sobre o Analytics ou TagManager, não sei ao certo, mas também não é sobre o buscador;
- [FAZER UPLOAD DE ARQUIVO PARA INSTANCIA GOOGLE CLOUD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366055/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-para-instancia-google-cloud)

  - Pergunta sobre Google Cloud;
- [Google News API - Utilização do Curl com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365253/google-news-api-utiliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-curl-com-php)

  - Pergunta sobre Google News;
- [O que quer dizer a licença MIT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364189/o-que-quer-dizer-a-licen%c3%a7a-mit)

  - Pergunta sobre a licença MIT. Google?

E por aí vai. Ou seja, parece que a maioria das perguntas usam a tag de forma errada e as que usam de forma correta, para referenciar o buscador de conteúdo da Google, vejo que poderiam utilizar a tag [seo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) da mesma forma, sem prejudicar a pergunta.

Então, precisamos mesmo da [google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google)? Em que momento é realmente necessário utilizar essa tag que outras já existentes não podem substitui-la?

Comment: Faltou a tag Dev-Tools https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dev-tools ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, mas ao meu ver todas essas poderia ter apenas a tag `seo` sem saírem prejudicadas. Não vejo a tag `google` realmente necessária nelas.

Comment: Acho que ainda seria útil para casos específicos do **buscador do google** utilizar algo como [tag:google-seo], já que a [tag:seo] é mais genérica...

Comment: Sim, e não. Ela parece ser útil, mas quase sempre usada erradamente. Algumas gravemente, mas isso vale pra muitas *tags*, tem casos que você fica se perguntando porque a pessoa colocou aquela *tag* ali, parece quase aleatório. Não sou a favor de matar um *tag* bem útil só porque as pessoas usam errado (se usaram uma certa e 50 erradas, aí pode :D). Boa partes desses casos seria melhor `google-xxx`, quem sabe todas, aí a *tag* poderia ser desnecessária mesmo. Teria que fazer uma análise mais profunda de todas perguntas dela.